# Interval of Initial Value for which Separation of Variables Results in a Well-Defined Solution of IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used separation of variables to solve $\frac {dP}{dt} = (b - aP)P, P(0) = P_0 \in \Bbb R$ and found the following solution: $$ P = \frac {bc{e^b}^t}{1+ac{e^b}^t}$$

However, I am unsure how to go about finding the interval of the initial value $P_0$ that would guarantee a well-defined solution $P(t)$.

Comment: what was the original problem?

Comment: The original problem was to solve the IVP above using separation of variables, and then to find the interval of initial values that would guarantee a well-defined solution.

Comment: Is the IVP $P^\prime =(b-aP)P$ with $P(0)=P_0\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, this is the IVP